# Is it normal include_once self?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP. I'm analyzing an existing source code and found this.

```php
// this is the some.php itself!!!
<?
include_once("./some.php"); // is this normal?
...
?>
```

Comment: Why would you need that first of all? The code is there only..

Comment: we never needed to include same file inside itself , its logically wrong,

Comment: May be is should be `..` like this  `include_once("../some.php");` to include file from once folder back with same file name, it is possible.

Comment: FIY, there is no `some.php` in the parent directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO.

There is no reason to include current file, itself.

If using include() not include_once(), it raise infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `include_once()` statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the `include()` statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.

As the name suggests, it will be included just once. There is no reason to do it..